# Jenkins - Jasmine reporter doesn't generate reports for protractor E2E tests

Tags: angular, jenkins, junit, protractor, end-to-end

I want to put my tests on jenkins and generate reports through Jasmine reporter.
The console shows succes but no report is generated .

I tried to make a folder manually but nothing new .
I tried using my local protractor.conf.js configuration , it worked but it doesn't give a report that's why I am looking for how to generate them.

package.json

```
  "name": "chapter-11-code",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/wasshj/testingangularendtoend.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "lint": "tslint",
    "webdriver-circle": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false --versions.chrome=2.40",
    "webdriver-update": "webdriver-manager update --gecko false",
    "tsc": "tsc"
  },
  "author": "Craig Nishina <craig.nishina@gmail.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.41",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.2",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "3.0.4",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-reporters": "2.2.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "protractor": "5.1.1",
    "selenium-webdriver": "3.0.1",
    "ts-node": "1.3.0",
    "typescript": "2.2.2"
  }
}
```

protractor.conf.js

```
const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    'e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: (process.env.IS_CIRCLE ? ['--headless'] : [])
    }
  },
  directConnect: !process.env.IS_JENKINS,
  baseUrl: 'https://testing-angular-applications.github.io',

  // Jasmine
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  onPrepare: ()=> {
    if (process.env.IS_JENKINS) {
      let jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
      let junitReporter = new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
        savePath: 'output/',
        consolidateAll: false
      });
      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(junitReporter);
    } else {
      let specReporter = new SpecReporter({
        spec: { displayStacktrace: true }
      });
      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(specReporter);
    }
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.json'
    });
  }
};
```

Script (on Jenkins)

```
export IS_JENKINS=true   
npm install    
npm run webdriver-update
```

Result

```
+ npm run webdriver-update

> chapter-11-code@1.0.0 webdriver-update /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/pjk11
> webdriver-manager update --gecko false
....
[12:03:41] I/file_manager - creating folder /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/pjk11/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdrive...
Xvfb stopping
Finished: SUCCESS
```

I followed every step of the angular testing book but no report is generated.

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED , I had to set **directConnect** to true.

Another point , sometimes you have to make the directory manually .

protractor.conf.js

```
exports.config = {
  directConnect: true ,
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: (['--headless']) 
    }
  },
  baseUrl: 'https://testing-angular-applications.github.io',
  specs: ['e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'],
  onPrepare: () => {
      let jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
      let junitReporter = new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
        savePath: 'output/',
        consolidateAll: false
      });
      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(junitReporter);
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e'
    });

  },
};
```